# Using Dark Menu Bar and Dock

Tags: macos, dock, menu-bar

[image]

In the ten minutes since I have updated my OS I have restarted the computer three times (I was testing something with displays having separate spaces, and a restart is easier than logging in). Each time it's started back up I've had to *uncheck* that box.

After reading [Cannot disable "Dark Menu Bar" on Mac OS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250530/cannot-disable-dark-menu-bar-on-mac-os-x) I think there is a good chance my preference files have been corrupted (since installing El Capitan deleted all my system preference files). I don't know how to fix them.

I've never had a problem with the menu bar or it's color before. Can I stop this from happening a fourth or fifth time?

Comment: Did you try the solution proposed in the link you provided?

Comment: I did not. That problem is different than mine and I thought the answers where specific to it. Plus, none of the suggestions worked for the asker... But it is worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart your Mac.
Do not change any settings

Execute `chmod -RN ~/Library/` in terminal.

It'll restore permissions for your library folder.
After the command have finished running (it can take from seconds to several minutes) try to change the dark setting, and restart.

Comment: Okay. So that didn't work. This time my computer was sleep for about 13 hours and when I opened it the dark menu bar was back. I checked **System Preferences** (to do one of the suggestions from the post I linked) and decided to check **Accessibility**, which lead me to quitting **f.lux**. And as soon as the app closed my menu bar went back to normal.